# How to upgrade disutils package PyYAML?

Tags: pip, pyyaml

I was trying to install **chatterbot** which has a dependency on **PyYAML=3.12**. In my Ubuntu machine installed **PyYAML** version is 3.11. So I used the following command to upgrade **PyYAML**:

`sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade PyYAML`

But it gives the following error:

> Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

My **pip3** version is 10.0.0.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You should always install programs like chatterbot in a virtualenv, using the latest version of Python (probably not what Ubuntu is using for there system Python). That way you can use whatever version of a library you need, without possible breaking system programs. (For PyYAML 3.12, which has minimal changes from 3.11, that is not so much an issue, but there are packages that would break things).

Comment: @Anthon Please turn your comment into an answer. I think it should be considered the top answer to this question.

Comment: @Anthon yeah, except when your installing in a Docker container

Comment: @CpILL you should use python virtual envs *also* in docker containers

Comment: @howaryoo Really, why? The docker container _is_ a virtual environment

Comment: @CpILL the docker container is not a virtual env for your python interpreter.  It is an isolated env for your processes. 
As far as python is concerned using a venv in your dev env, in production in a EC2 instance or in a docker container is the best practice because:
https://vsupalov.com/virtualenv-in-docker/
you can also add as many layers as you want say conda + poetry. There is not performance penalty.

Comment: @howaryoo there is nothing in that article to convince me that its worth the effort. "OS-level changes down the line" can't happen as that is _the point_ of containers, the OS is fixed, and is also a clean install.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found [in this Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4805) that **pip 10 no longer uninstalls distutils packages**. So I downgraded to pip 8.1.1. And now it works.

And to downgrade pip, I used the following:

`sudo -H pip3 install pip==8.1.1`

Comment: Why version 8.1.1? Just curious but this worked great!

Comment: I ended up with removing folder from `distutils`: `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml`, `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyYAML-*`

Comment: @Tony-Caffe well, before upgrading my pip version was 8.1.1. So I downgraded to 8.1.1. But I think it should also work for 8.0.*

Answer (score 195):

Try using the `--ignore-installed` flag:

`sudo -H pip3 install --ignore-installed PyYAML`

This works because to upgrade a package, `pip` first uninstalls the old version, then installs the new version. It is the uninstall step that fails for distutils packages. With the `--ignore-installed` flag, the uninstall step is skipped and the new version is simply installed on top of the old one.

Answer (score 76):

You can try this:

```
pip install --ignore-installed PyYAML
```

Comment: This seems like the most sensible answer... no regrets

Comment: Worked without breaking things

Answer (score 13):

### Issue:

> Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

### Solution : Remove Dist Package and RUN

`sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml`

`sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyYAML-*`

Removing folder from distutils works

Comment: This doesn't work, even after removing dist stuff, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I personnaly had PyYAML installed on anaconda, just executing 'conda remove PyYAML' and then executing my pip command worked.

Comment: This broke my Anaconda. Numpy was gone. I had to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration that this could be due to a conda install. Instead of removing, I instead used `conda update` which has fixed my `pip install` without the other dependency breaking mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

```
conda remove PyYAML
```

#### conda remove will take time

```
pip install chatterbot
pip install chatterbot_corpus
```

In this way it sloved my error while I was trying **from chatterbot import chatbot**

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue where the `PyYAML` package was installed by conda. There is another answer to use `conda remove`.

Instead I have got round this issue using `conda update PyYAML`, effectively using conda to update the dependency which pip is trying itself to update.

Answer (score 1):

If `--ignore-installed` is **NOT the case** for you, and you are running Debian/Ubuntu, then you can try following solution.

PyYAML could possibly be installed with `apt`, as a dependency of another package.

To debug that:

1. Detect a package name: run `apt list --installed | grep python` and search for any `yaml` occurrence.
2. Let's say, you've detected a package `python3-yaml`.
3. Search for reverse dependencies: `apt-cache rdepends --installed python3-yaml`

Then you can:

- either delete unused reverse deps along with `python3-yaml`
- or delete `python3-yaml` via `dpkg -r --force-depends python3-yaml` and
  re-install it via `pip`
- or make a decision on your own and share results in comments

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyYAML-*
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyYAML-*
sudo -H pip3 install --ignore-installed PyYAML
```