# Cannot uninstall chardet

Tags: pip, chardet

I've been trying to uninstall chardet using pip, but I get the following error:

"Cannot uninstall 'chardet'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

My pip version is 10.0.0, python 2.7.14, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Remove files/directories manually. Or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911928/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip cannot uninstall <package>: "It is a distutils installed project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807511/pip-cannot-uninstall-package-it-is-a-distutils-installed-project)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The location of chardet can be determined by running the following commands in the python console.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> print chardet.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet/__init__.pyc
```

Then just manually remove the following folders/*.egg-info file.

```
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet-<your-version>.egg-info
rm -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet
```

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav What's the issue with seaborn?

Comment: deleting files managed by your operating system package manager is not a good idea -- this is how you break your system