# How to uninstall PyXB?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, pyxb

I've tried uninstalling PyXB from my PyCharm and also using the pip command line.

I've tried:
  pip uninstall PyXB
and I get the error msg. listed below:

```
    C:\Users\NTier> pip list
    Package         Version
    --------------- ---------
    certifi         2018.4.16
    chardet         3.0.4
    click           6.7
    entrypoints     0.2.3
    idna            2.7
    jsonconfig-tool 1.5
    keyring         13.2.1
    messages        0.4.3
    pip             18.1
    python-box      3.2.0
    pywin32-ctypes  0.1.2
    PyXB            1.2.6
    recordclass     0.5
    requests        2.19.1
    setuptools      39.0.1
    urllib3         1.23
    validus         0.3.0

    C:\Users\NTier>pip uninstall PyXB

Cannot uninstall 'PyXB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

"remove it manually" I've looked. It's not obvious how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot uninstall chardet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915951/cannot-uninstall-chardet)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+uninstall+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project

Comment: In short, remove it manually.

Comment: "remove it manually"
I've looked. It's not obvious how to do that.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944920/6390175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete

folder C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyxb 
and
file C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyXB-1.2.6-py3.7.egg-info

then run 
pip list
to confirm.