# Cannot uninstall 'pandas' (distutils installed project)

Tags: python, pandas, installation, conda, distutils

I have created a conda environment where I am installing all the stuff I need.

I already had installed the `pandas` library, but I need to upgrade it to the latest version.

However, when I try `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` I get the following error:

```
  Found existing installation: pandas 0.15.2
Cannot uninstall 'pandas'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get remove pandas`, but this get me a message saying that the pandas package cannot be found.

In case is relevant, I am in Ubuntu 16.04 and using python 3.6.3

Comment: Why not just use conda to install Pandas?

Comment: @darthbith thanks, I forgot I had that option and it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rasa core installation existing package found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452344/rasa-core-installation-existing-package-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911928/7976758

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm unable to reproduce the error, you can try:

1) Reduce version

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==18.0
```

Try to re-install package

```
pip install xxx --disable-pip-version-check
```

At last, recover the latest version for pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

2) `pip install -I==18.0 -r requirements.txt`

3) Try removing manually from 'site-packages'

These solutions were found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247)